# AAVE flash loan borrow more tokens always error at hardhat

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

I'm using hardhat to doing AAVE flash loan, when I borrow one token, is successful, but borrow > 1 tokens, always error.

＊ deploy on eth mainnet-fork

**flash-loans-test.js**

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const hre = require("hardhat");

describe("AaveFlashLoans", function () {
    it("Excute flashloans", async function () {
        const contractAddress = "0xB53C1a33016B2DC2fF3653530bfF1848a515c8c5";
        const flashLoansFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("AaveFlashLoans");
        const flashLoans = await flashLoansFactory.deploy(contractAddress);
        await flashLoans.deployed();

        const token = await ethers.getContractAt("IERC20", "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2"); //weth

        const BALANCE_AMOUNT = ethers.utils.parseEther("2");

        await hre.network.provider.request({
            method: "hardhat_impersonateAccount",
            params: ["0xf07704777d6bc182bf2c67fbda48913169b84983"],
        });

        const signer = await ethers.getSigner("0xf07704777d6bc182bf2c67fbda48913169b84983");

        await token
            .connect(signer)
            .transfer(flashLoans.address, BALANCE_AMOUNT);

        await flashLoans.myFlashLoanCall();

        const balance = await token.balanceOf(flashLoans.address)

        console.log(balance);
    });
});
```

**AaveFlashLoans.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import {SafeMath} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import {IERC20} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import {FlashLoanReceiverBase} from "./FlashLoanReceiverBase.sol";
import {ILendingPoolAddressesProvider} from "./ILendingPoolAddressesProvider.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract AaveFlashLoans is FlashLoanReceiverBase {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    constructor(ILendingPoolAddressesProvider _addressProvider)
        FlashLoanReceiverBase(_addressProvider)
    {}

    function executeOperation(
        address[] calldata assets,
        uint256[] calldata amounts,
        uint256[] calldata premiums,
        address,
        bytes calldata
    ) external override returns (bool) {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
            uint256 amountOwing = amounts[i].add(premiums[i]);
            IERC20(assets[i]).approve(address(LENDING_POOL), amountOwing);
            console.log(amounts[i]);
            console.log(premiums[i]);
        }

        return true;
    }

    function myFlashLoanCall() public {
        address receiverAddress = address(this);

        address[] memory assets = new address[](1);
        assets[0] = address(0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2); // weth

        uint256[] memory amounts = new uint256[](1);
        amounts[0] = 1 ether;

        uint256[] memory modes = new uint256[](1);
        modes[0] = 0;

        address onBehalfOf = address(this);
        bytes memory params = "";
        uint16 referralCode = 0;

        LENDING_POOL.flashLoan(
            receiverAddress,
            assets,
            amounts,
            modes,
            onBehalfOf,
            params,
            referralCode
        );
    }
}
```

above code is successful
[successful image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQX7Z.png)
[successful image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QXSN.png)

but when I add 2 tokens, it will error

**AaveFlashLoans.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import {SafeMath} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import {IERC20} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import {FlashLoanReceiverBase} from "./FlashLoanReceiverBase.sol";
import {ILendingPoolAddressesProvider} from "./ILendingPoolAddressesProvider.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract AaveFlashLoans is FlashLoanReceiverBase {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    constructor(ILendingPoolAddressesProvider _addressProvider)
        FlashLoanReceiverBase(_addressProvider)
    {}

    function executeOperation(
        address[] calldata assets,
        uint256[] calldata amounts,
        uint256[] calldata premiums,
        address,
        bytes calldata
    ) external override returns (bool) {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
            uint256 amountOwing = amounts[i].add(premiums[i]);
            IERC20(assets[i]).approve(address(LENDING_POOL), amountOwing);
            console.log(amounts[i]);
            console.log(premiums[i]);
        }

        return true;
    }

    function myFlashLoanCall() public {
        address receiverAddress = address(this);

        address[] memory assets = new address[](2);
        assets[0] = address(0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2); // weth
        assets[1] = address(0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7); // usdt

        uint256[] memory amounts = new uint256[](2);
        amounts[0] = 1 ether;
        amounts[1] = 1 ether;

        uint256[] memory modes = new uint256[](2);
        modes[0] = 0;
        modes[1] = 0;

        address onBehalfOf = address(this);
        bytes memory params = "";
        uint16 referralCode = 0;

        LENDING_POOL.flashLoan(
            receiverAddress,
            assets,
            amounts,
            modes,
            onBehalfOf,
            params,
            referralCode
        );
    }
}
```

above code is error
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63BuZ.png)

Please help, thanks a lot lot lot lot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the [USDT token](https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7) has 6 decimals, by inputting the amount as 1 ether, this corresponds to the amount: 1000000000000 USDT. There is not enough availableLiquidity in the pool to borrow this amount, so this is why the tx is reverting. If you reduce the amount, then it should succeed.